# How to produce a wordcloud in python with consistent word positioning?

Tags: python, position, word-cloud

I am trying to create an animated word cloud in Python (3.7) using the wordcloud package.

The problem is that the words change position every run (understandably). Is there way to keep the positions the same, or better still make an animated wordcloud in Python?

My idea was to run it multiple times with increasingly larger sections of my text corpus until complete. These snapshots could then be stitched together into a GIF.

```py
for i in range(0,int(len(topic3)/5)):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1600, height=800, max_words=50).generate(str(topic9["Verbatims"].iloc[0:i*5]))
    # Open a plot of the generated image.
    plt.figure( figsize=(20,10), facecolor='k')
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
#     plt.show()
    name = "word_plot_" + str(i)
    plt.savefig(name)
```

Comment: If i got you correctly, you're trying to make a step by step animation of word cloud which on each step adds a new word to cloud, keeping the existing ones on ther places. The problem with this is, constraints change on each addition of new words. For example, you could have 4 words placed beautifully, but adding a 5th one will have to squish existing ones, or it should be placed at some tiny space  without bothering others by scaling down the word to tiny. Or you'd need to expand your canvas on each iteration.

Comment: Best would be modifying the wordcloud's code or overriding some parts to your needs.

Comment: @altunyurt Something along those lines. As it reads through a passage of text there would be a lot of rapid changing at the start, but as it continues it should stabilise and just the size of the words will change as their count does. I can make an animation that makes it "frame-by-frame", but the words change position substantially meaning that the animation is somewhat manic.

Comment: Ah i see, you only need to scale up / down already existing words. But still, every now and then you'll have to add new words, which'll affect the whole distribution. Also, - assuming that https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/wordcloud/wordcloud.py#L371 is the project you are using - you can see that frequencies are necessary to calculate the positions, which'll be constantly changing on each iteration, while the placements should stay the same, which is a not easily satisfiable constraint.

Comment: You might, however modify https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/wordcloud/query_integral_image.pyx#L7 in a way that looks for already provided coordinates and tries to adjust them slightly if any collusion occurs.